# Is there something similar to curves' tilt for skin modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to create shoelaces with skin modifier. I use Ctrl-A Y to flatten cross-section, and all looks good, but when I start to move vertices the angle of flattened part gets distorted and it does not confirm to the shoe surface. For curves I would use Tilt to solve this problem, but I do not know if something like this is possible for skin modifier as well.

Is there a 'tilt-like' way to control skin modifier? Am I better off to use curves in this situation?

Comment: I would use curves

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use skin?

Comment: I do enjoy using skin modifier wrapped between two subsurface modifiers when I can. I do it because I can use the same tools I use for retopo and modeling and I tend to be faster at making what I need than with curves

Comment: Unless you're planning on animating the laces later, I would use curves, as  GianCowFilms has already suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the very nature of the *Skin* modifier, this is not possible. Vertices do not have any rotational data, only location data. Because of this, it would be impossible to "tilt" the *Skin* modifier result, as it uses vertices to interpolate the resulting mesh.

Most of the examples I have seen the modeller is using curves. By using extrusion and bevel you can make great flat laces, and round ones are even easier. They also are completely editable at all times.

I would strongly recommend using curves for this.

There is one example [**here**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13393/is-it-possible-to-hide-curves-guides-in-edit-mode) that you can see. There is also a solution for one of the issues you might run into.