# Is it possible to hide curves' guides in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

In this example I use Nurbs curves to create shoe laces and it becomes quite hard to operate curves in the regions of loops and knots because of the curves' tilt/scale guides (not sure how to call them). I would really like to hide these guides when I edit curves. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those black lines are the normals for the curve.

**Blender 2.79:**

You can change the way they are displayed in the "Curve Display" tab.

[image]

**Blender 2.80**

[image]

To make them smaller change the **normal size**.

To make them disappear uncheck the **normals box**.