# How to turn a bezier into having squiggly lines

Tags: path, bezier-curves

[image]Hi! So I’m still new to blender but the thing is, I don’t know how to turn my path/bezier into having those squiggly lines so that I can edit them correctly. I’ve been watching videos but they’ve never mentioned anything on how to do it. I want to turn my normal circle to having the squiggly lines like what I’ve shown in the pictures, I’d really appreciate it if someone can help me.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13393/is-it-possible-to-hide-curves-guides-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the normals, go into the *Viewport Display* panel to display them:

[image]